# Science Fiction movie which used Eagles from “Space: 1999?”

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

I seem to remember seeing a science fiction movie in the late 1970s or 1980s which seemed very cheap.

As I remember, the eagle spaceships from *Space: 1999* were used as alien spaceships instead of the flying saucers you would expect. I think the plot had something about aliens coming to Earth up to no good.

Comment: The footage got used all over the place; https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0074115/ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow_(TV_special) / https://www.allsci-fi.com/viewtopic.php?p=35783&sid=ce616d48e15d6cf835d5c521545c27fc

Comment: Certain episodes of Space 1999 were edited together to make TV movies.https://catacombs.space1999.net/main/pguide/up013.html

Comment: this video on youtube lists some of the places footage from space 1999 turned as stock footage used for other productions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-OtUU260zQ

Comment: @m. a. golding Very comprehensive list of places footage of Space 1999 was used can be found here, after a quick read you might be looking for the Sheriff and The Satellite kid as this is noted to include shots of hawks... have a read and see if something jumps out at you... https://catacombs.space1999.net/main/crguide/vclip1.html

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to take a leap and suggest you are looking for [*The Sheriff and the Satellite Kid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sheriff_and_the_Satellite_Kid) from 1979. It was a low budget film about a humanoid alien played by Cary Guffey (Yes, Barry from [*Close Encounters of the Third Kind*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind) (1977), talk about being type cast.) stranded on Earth. It does use an effects shot from *Space: 1999*.

The film is available on YouTube here:

The effect shot from *Space: 1999* appears at 1 hour 24 minutes, almost at the end of the film. If you look closely you can see two hawks flanking the large warship seen in the episode “[War Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Games_(Space:_1999)).”

Also worth noting that an episode of *Wonder Woman* used footage from *Space: 1999*. *Wonder Woman* also had episodes about UFO's so it's possible you are conflating them together. The wonder woman episode titled “[Time Bomb](https://wonder-woman.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_307:_Time_Bomb)” used effects shots from several *Space: 1999* episodes. The episode with UFO's is titled “[The Starships are Coming](https://wonder-woman.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_315:_The_Starships_are_Coming)” but I don't believe this used footage from *Space: 1999*. It's bang in the time range though, broadcast in 1980 so easy to get it confused.

A very detailed list of where *Space: 1999* footage appears in other programs and films can be found here.

https://catacombs.space1999.net/main/crguide/vclip1.html

Comment: The first film mentioned (original title "Uno sceriffo extraterrestre... poco extra e molto terrestre") is notable for featuring Bud Spencer, who was a very famous actor in Italy during that time period, as the protagonist. I would have never expected to see it mentioned in an answer concerning Space: 1999 props.

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility is the movie [*The Day After Tomorrow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow_(TV_special)), 1975, starring Brian Blessed and Nick Tate (both were in *Space: 1999*) and was produced by Gerry Anderson.

Many of the ships were reused from *Space: 1999*, with slight modifications (though, to be honest, I don't particularly remember an Eagle per se), and the special effects style was pure *Space: 1999*. Many of the effects people from *Space: 1999* worked on *The Day After Tomorrow*.

To quote the [*The Day After Tomorrow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow_(TV_special)) Wikipedia page:

> “The visual style of *Space: 1999* provided inspiration to both effects artist Martin Bower, who built the scale models, and production designer Reg Hill, who recycled sets from *Space: 1999* to create the *Altares* interiors.”
>
> …
>
> “They were built from parts of the Ultra Probe set originally made for the Space: 1999 episode "[Dragon's Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Domain)", along with design elements from other episodes. Other sets and props were also recycled from the earlier series.”

[image]

Answer (score 6):

After searching the list of *Space:1999* appearances in various movies and tv shows linked to by skyjack's answer  https://catacombs.space1999.net/main/crguide/vclip1.html I think that the movie I am thinking of is probably  *God Told Me to* (1976).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Told_Me_To

Comment: glad you found what you were looking for! If I'm not mistaken you can mark your own answer correct!

Comment: After 48 hours, IIRC